# Cannot create a new GridStore

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs

I am using Gridfs to create a file and save it in mongodb. I am using console.log to figure out where the error might be. My web app allows users to create a text file and the web app will save it in mongodb. In order to save the file I am using Gridfs, however my program does not pass the line `var gridStores = new GridStore (db, names, "w");`. I can't seem to figure out why, I figured there must be something wrong with my new GridStore. Thank you for your help.

saveFile.js:

```
var Files = require('C:/Users/OneDrive/workspace/Editor/Models/files.js');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('C:/Users/OneDrive/workspace/Editor/Models/users.js');
var db = mongoose.connection.db;
var GridStore = mongoose.mongo.GridStore;
var Grid = mongoose.mongo.Grid;
var SaveFile = function(names, contents){
console.log("inside SaveFile");
console.log("this is the name: " + names);
console.log("this is the content: " + contents);
var gridStores = new GridStore (db, names, "w");
console.log("pass new gridStore ");
gridStores.open(function(err, gridStores){
    console.log("inside open gridstor");
    gridStores.write(this.contents, function(err, gridStores){
        assert.equal(null, err);
        gridStores.close(function(err, result){
            assert.equal(null, err);
        });
    });
});
console.log("passed GridStore");
findorCreateUser();
}
findOrCreateUser = function(){
console.log("Inside Create user");
    User.findOne({'username' :  username },
        function(err, user) {
            if (err){
                console.log('Error in SignUp: '+err);
                return done(err);
            }
            if (user) {
                user.files = gridStore;
                user.save(function(err) {
                    if (err){
                        console.log('Error in Saving file:'+err);  
                        throw err;  
                    }
                    console.log('File Saved');    
                    return done(null, user);
                    });
                } 
            else {
                console.log('User already exists with username: '+username);
                return done(null, false, req.flash('message',
                    'User Already Exists'));
            }
        });
}
module.exports = SaveFile;
```

Here is my user schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;
var UserSchema = new Schema({
username:{type: String, required: true},
password:{type: String, required: true},
    files:{type: Schema.Types.Mixed, required: false}
}, {collection: 'Logins'});

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
var user = this;
bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
    mongoose.set('debug', true);
    if (err) 
        return next(err);
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) 
            return callback(err, hash);
        user.password = hash;
        next();
    });

  });
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not pass"? Is there an error message?

Comment: I mean that it does not go to the next line, which is `console.log("pass new gridStore ");`. I do not get any error messages either.

Comment: I think the bug is names is undefined,